# Why are iOS UDIDs case sensitive?

Tags: ios, iphone, hex, case-sensitive, udid

iOS device UDIDs (Unique Device IDs) are strings of hexadecimal numbers. Why are they treated as case sensitive (when we want to register them for testing purposes) ?

UDIDs are generated from SHA-1  Hash function and then converted to Hex. So for all intents and purposes A==a, B==b, .. F==f.

However if we use uppercase, the registration of IPhone for testing dont work. Is this an Apple bug?

http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/UDID

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

Comment: "Doctor, doctor it hurts when I do this...".  Why don't you avoid uppercasing them, then?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming direct question.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Like ceejayoz said, there is no convention for this.. So the answer for your questions is:

Because _Apple_ wants like this.

Comment: did you find any solution on change the upper case udid to lower case udid?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, there's just no standard and it's up the folks implementing which to use (or to make it case-insensitive). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal

> There is no universal convention to use lowercase or uppercase for the letter digits, and each is prevalent or preferred in particular environments by community standards or convention.

Since you're having trouble when you uppercase the UUID, *stop doing it*.

Comment: ceejayoz,  trojanfoe  : my clients keep on sending me UDID in uppercases. Not sure how they generate it, probably using some 3rd party apps. Anyways, mathematically the cases are equivalent in hex, so it does NOT make any sense to distinguish between them. It should have been case insensitive.

Comment: @exifguy Well, they're apparently not, so lowercase them and move on to larger programming difficulties.